# SSH not working after macOS 10.15.6 update

Tags: catalina, ssh

I am experiencing a `timeout connection error` when using ssh from my MacBook to connect to an external server. The problem started immediately after having updated to macOS 10.15.6. I could connect smoothly before that. The server is working correctly, I can connect from other machines.

```
$ ssh -v T800                   
OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/XYZ/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/XYZ/.ssh/config line 22: Applying options for T800
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 47: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] port 22.
debug1: connect to address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 22: Operation timed out
ssh: connect to host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 22: Operation timed out
```

`/etc/ssh/ssh_config` contains a bunch of commented lines and then:

```
Host *
        SendEnv LANG LC_*
```

While `/Users/XYZ/.ssh/config` for T800 is:

```
Host T800
        Hostname xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
        User john
        Port 22
        UserKnownHostsFile ~/.ssh/know_hosts
```

The firewall of my MacBook is turned off, and the one on the server is correctly configured. I can ping the server from my MacBook and I can access it via ssh from other machines, including my second MacBook wich is still running an older version of macOS.

A similar (yet different) problem is described [here](https://tyler.io/so-uh-i-think-catalina-10154-broke-ssh/), I tried the solution proposed but it didn't work in my case.

Any clue?

Comment: Have a look at the last two lines where is says “Operation timed out.”. This means that your SSH client tried to establish the connection, however it sat waiting for the server to respond.  It gave up when it didn’t get a response.  Typically a firewall will cause a rejection, but check your and the server for firewall(s) between you two.  Also make sure that the server is up and running and accepting connections.

Comment: The firewall on my Mac is turned off. The server is well configured, it was working before the update and it is working from other machines, I can ssh in the server from other computers. Pinging the server IP works as well.

Comment: Try increasing verbosity (`-vvv`). Also - try to compare any relevant ssh config files (user and system ones) from the working mac - are there any differences? (I guess that the system upgrade has overwritten something?)

Comment: I have tried the resetting NVRAM, but it only works the first time. After that it always indicates timeout Any other suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @ShaoqunZhou I don't know how to help. It worked for me and I don't have problems with it anymore.

Comment: Does updating to 10.15.7 fix the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow resetting NVRAM solved the issue. I am still puzzled about the cause of the bug, but at least I got ssh working properly again.

Here is a link to an Apple help-document on how to do this: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063

Comment: There is **nothing** in NVRAM that has anything to do with networking.  You can see the contents with `nvram -xp`.  More than likely is was the reboot that naturally happens when you do an NVRAM reset.

Comment: I try reboot before applying above suggestion. Restart didn't help. Maybe full stop and start was a fix?

Answer (score 3):

My issue seems related to this one. Hope my solution will nudge others in the right direction.

I once updated my macOS to 10.15.4 and started having problems: `git pull` and `git push` would hang indefinitely for GitHub. Checked all the forums and tried all solutions, but nothing worked. I eventually started using a Linux laptop for git repositories. Returned to this problem today and got onto something.

Not only `git pull` and `git push` hang, but also `ssh -T git@github.com`. Decided to replace `github.com` with the actual IP address and it worked!

I ran:

```
$ ssh -T git@github.com
^c (hung indefinitely)
$ nslookup github.com
192.30.255.113
$ ssh -T git@192.30.255.113
Hi user! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

I didn't try to dig deeper yet, just used a workaround:

```
$ git remote add alt git@192.30.255.113:user/repo.git
```

Now to pull and push from GitHub, I run:

- `git pull alt master`
- `git push alt master`

**Update**

I don't have issues pinging github.com, so my DNS servers are set up correctly. The DNS resolution issue only shows up when I try to ssh to github.com.

Answer (score 0):

I finally made it works.

Open **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **General**, then login to ssh in the Terminal. It will give you a warning about 'ssh' with options of **Put in trash** or **Cancel**. Hit **Cancel** then in the **System Preferences** panel, you will see that ssh is blocked. Hit **Open anyway**, then it works.

Same thing with sftp.