# Unable to SSH to other servers after Monterey 12.5 upgrade

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, ssh

For some reason ssh connections from my computer to other devices do not seem to work after OSx upgrade, have already restarted it, shut down, started it back up.

Do not see anything being blocked within system preferences >> security, I am out of ideas tbh...

This is what I get

```
~ % ssh 192.168.77.79 -vv
OpenSSH_8.6p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/* matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 54: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 192.168.77.79 is address
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.77.79 [192.168.77.79] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 192.168.77.79 port 22: Operation timed out
ssh: connect to host 192.168.77.79 port 22: Operation timed out
```

Never seen this before... just confirmed that able to ssh from a different host, so has to be something on my local laptop :s

How can I troubleshoot this further?

Comment: Does adding two more “v” added show another error in ssh? I would also run nmap to be sure your Mac sees port 22 open.

Comment: Already did a telnet against the server on 22, no issues, vv used to be extra verbose level, not sure if still a thing ;)

A buddy of mine also did the update and having a similar issue.....

Comment: Try increasing verbosity (`-vvv`). - https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/483531/8888 But if Telnet is listening on that port, there is your answer…

Comment: I think he means he tried a telnet connection to port 22.  If he got the OpenSSH banner, then the daemon on the other end is listening.

Comment: [Could very well be](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/400102/5472), will have to wait for the OP to make an edit @MarcWilson

Comment: Did you tried to remove the destination host from the ~/ssh/known_hosts file ? (Make a copy of the file before in case it messes up)

Comment: Interestingly enough it seems to be an issue just at work, no issues at home, only happened after the Monterey upgrade, it is so disconcerting, we have no clue as in why is this even happening, there is no blocked traffic, windows/linux computers have no issue, only Macs

Comment: @PtitXav yup, already tried it

```
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.77.79 [192.168.77.79] port 22.
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IP_TOS 0x48
debug1: connect to address 192.168.77.79 port 22: Operation timed out
ssh: connect to host 192.168.77.79 port 22: Operation timed out
```

Comment: Specifying [IPQoS in your ssh config file](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/444771/5472) should do the trick.